# File upload in Spring boot to add in sql db

Tags: sql, spring-boot, blob

I am working on the code but stuck. It should be able to read image file from web browser and convert into blob for sql db. I am using spring boot, hibernate, sql. no js or xml. The controller and the html codes are listed below.

```
@Controller    
@RequestMapping("imagefile")
public class ImagefileController {@RequestMapping(value = "menu", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String imageupload(Model model,  @RequestParam("id") int id, @RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile uploadFile,
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    //add photo upload coding here.
    String filename=uploadFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String uploadFilepath=Paths.get("." + File.separator, filename).toString();;

    //need to get the file into the input stream.

    //byte[] bytes = uploadFile.getBytes();
    //String filename1 = uploadFile.toString();
    //File f = new File(filename1);
    //f.getAbsolutePath();
    //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());
    //f.getAbsolutePath();
    Byte [] imagefile;

    //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filename1));
    //File filename = new FileInputStream(filename1.getBytes());
    //String uploadFilename = uploadFile.getOriginalFilename();
    //createSessionFactory().openSession();
    //Session session = sessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession(); //getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    //File uploadfile = new File(uploadfile);
   // Blob fileblob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(filename.getBytes()); //new FileInputStream(uploadfile), file1.length()
    Menu menu = menuDao.findOne(id);
    model.addAttribute("title", "Add images to the menu: " + menu.getName());
    System.out.println("Original Filename is:" + uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
    System.out.println("File Class is:" + uploadFile.getClass());
    System.out.println("Is the File Empty?:" + uploadFile.isEmpty());
    System.out.println("File size:" + uploadFile.getSize());
    System.out.println("File contentType:" + uploadFile.getContentType());
    //session.close();
    return "Imagefile/index";
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head th:replace="fragments :: head"></head>
<body class="container">

<nav th:replace="fragments :: navigation"></nav>


<h1 th:text="${title}"></h1>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="file" title=" "  accept="image/*"/>

    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="add photo" />


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

-----dao------

```
@Repository
@Transactional
 public interface MenuDao extends CrudRepository<Menu, Integer>{
 }
```

-------entity for sql----

```
@Entity
public class Imagefile {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String filename;
@Lob
private Blob imagecontent;
@ManyToOne
private Menu menu;

//constructor
public Imagefile(int id, String filename, Blob imagecontent) {
    this.id = id;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.imagecontent = imagecontent;
}
public Imagefile() {}

//Getters and Setters - Accessors.

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public Blob getImagecontent() {
    return imagecontent;
}

public void setImagecontent(Blob imagecontent) {
    this.imagecontent = imagecontent;
}

public Menu getMenu() {
    return menu;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
}
}
```

Here is the output for the test.

`Original Filename is:40 Brookside.jpg
File Class is:class org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile
Is the File Empty?:false
File size:473735
File contentType:image/jpeg`

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: what corrections need to be done to make it work? In the test result, the file is read properly. Does FileInputStream or similar input stream processor need to be used to add the file into sql db?

Comment: I usually store my files in filesystem and the paths in db, so I can't really help me. Take a look here http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc

Comment: ok. how do you save the paths into the sql db? do you have similar code for me to look at?

Comment: The same way as you store a String in an SQL table, just that your String is something like : 'FOLDERPATH/YourFileName'.

Comment: ok.   `uploadFile.getBytes() or uploadFile.getInputStream()`
 gives `Unhandled exception:java.io.IOException. `

Answer (score 0):

Here how I'll proceed to store the file in FileSystem and path in DB.

```
public String imageupload(@RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile uploadFile,...) {

   String FILES_FOLDER = "C:/MyFilesDirectory/";
   String PHOTOS_FOLDER= "PHOTOS/";
   String photoName = uploadFile !=null ? uploadFile.getOriginalFileName(): null;
   String DIRECTORY  = FILES_FOLDER+PHOTOS_FOLDER+photoName;

   //Now we transfer the file to DIRECTORY
   File file = new File(DIRECTORY);
   //check if 'file' does not exist then create it 
   // finally :
   uploadFile.transferTo(file);
   //Then save 'DIRECTORY' in your db 
   menuDao.save(DIRECTORY); // I don't know what is inside your menuDao

}
```

Note that I am using `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam`.

**EDIT: LOADING FILE**

Example of code for displaying your image. Let's suppose you have this in your view

```
<img src="get-image" />
```

Then in your handler method you will have :

```
@RequestMapping("get-image" )
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(){
//retrieve your image from DB
//transform it to byte[]
// then return it
}
```

Comment: ok good. dao and @entity is added to the post above. Once the app is deployed on a web hosting server(eg Heroku), the `C:/drive mapped path` wont be available. How that would affect the users?

Comment: It is an option (that I prefer) than storing file bytes in db but you can keep your first solution if you prefer. I think storing file directly in db could slow the application, of course it depends of the size and the trafic. 
Regarding your dao, I'll make a new one : `public interface ImageDAO extends JpaRepository<ImageFile, Integer>{}` then use its save method to do the job.

Comment: yes i want to go with the first open to save the image file directly into the db. but my problem is that as the image file is passed thru the method`public String imageupload(Model model,  @RequestParam("id") int id, @RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile uploadFile,
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)` , the file is not responding to `uploadFile.getBytes() or uploadFile.getInputStream()` gives `Unhandled exception:java.io.IOException.`

Comment: Ok. Use an array of byte[] instead of InputStream. To transform your MultipartFile to bytes[], first convert it to file then you can get the bytes after that you can store it with @Lob. Conversion to file : `File file = new File( uploadFile.getOriginalFilename());
    uploadFile.transferTo(file);`

Comment: To transform the mutltipartfile uploadFile into bytes[], won't need the uploadFile to be saved in a local temp directory correct?

Comment: Yes, you transform directly the submitted file.

Comment: without creating a temp directory for the MultipartFile uploadFile in the app?

Comment: how to read the blob files to display the image? any thoughts on that?

Comment: To display the image you should send back array of bytes as response to your <img src="url_to_get_this_array" /> tag.

Comment: url means path of the images? but the images are sent to thymeleaf via model binding `model.addAttribute("imagefiles", menu.getImagefiles())`, and then in thymeleaf  `<tr th:each="image : ${imagefiles}"> <td><img th:src="@{${image.imagecontent}}"></img></td>`.  i listed the question with this id 44338433. please look at the details there. thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's suppose that you have a handler method which gets the file from database and returns byte[]. You'll have <img src="/url_to_call_that_method">. This should be enough to get your image...

Comment: ok. this means I need to change the controller from returning String to byte[]?  `@RequestMapping(value = "media-nenuid/{menuid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String postmedia(Model model, @ModelAttribute Imagefile 
newimgfile,@PathVariable int menuid ) { ....return "Imagefile/media-menuid"; }`. images can not be referenced via model binding? `model.addAttribute("imagefiles", menu.getImagefiles())`

Comment: ok. just curious why to use the @ResponseBody and not within the method `@RequestMapping(value = "media-nenuid/{menuid}", method=RequestMethod.GET) public String postmedia(Model model, @ModelAttribute Imagefile newimgfile,@PathVariable int menuid )                { bytes[] imagebytes =getimagebytesfromdb; model.addAttribute("imageinbytes",imagebytes);                                 ....return "Imagefile/media-menuid"; }`

Comment: isnt the `model.addAttribute` also allows the access of the image bytes to the  html browser via the html element/tag?

Comment: I did the same error in the past when I began learning Spring but I realized that this would  never work, because If you add a byte[] (which is an array) object in the model how do you get this in view side? I also misunderstood how <img /> works so I let you discovering how it works. Besides that, when you read a file you read a flux of bytes and in the model we add a "compact" object.

Comment: @ResponseBody as its name indicates add the returned value into the response's body, this annotation is used when you don't need to render a view specially in a REST context. In this case <img /> requests for image file and not need to render a view. See docs for more details

Comment: yes learning by trial and error makes things better. so basically model.addAttribute wont be able to process stream of byte[] or consective segments of the array, since image is spread over many segments within array. however in this task,the image bytes need to be sent/returned in a motion or in a stream, thats why the model.addAttribute wont work, correct?

Comment: the above editing you did is good for 1 image, but what if there are series of images to be displayed thru the same handler/method within the same controller, how that can be returned to the call made to the handler from the html template <img src="url_to_get_this_array" /> tag.

Comment: You can add a request parameter to identify each image <img src="url_to_get_this_array?imageId=id" /> then proceed...

Comment: in a table there are several images associated to a foreign key, and the table has primary id as well. the images are displayed based on this foreign key. whatever images are there associated to the foreign key, all of them should be displayed. images are not displayed based on image_id itself, but rather based on foreign key. with that said, request parameter for each image_id, is still the way to go?

Comment: In this tag `<img th:src="@{/Imagedlfile/{image.getId()}}"  />` , `{image.getId()}` intends to pass a String id from view to a method. Method then takes the value of the  `{image.getId()}` and work on converting String id into primitive int. is the conversion possible?

Comment: Yes, Spring does this automatically for you.

Comment: but Spring is passing `{image.getId()}` as string. The output of this is `{image`. output is not the content or the value of the `{image.getId()}`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but to get the value in your handler method you can get the id by using @PathVariable